# Facing Fatal Error: SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName

Tags: android, react-native, react-hooks, crashlytics, react-android

Facing non-reproducible error of soloader on released version. Getting following logs on crashlytics ..

react-native: 0.64.4

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so
    SoSource 0: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.bcferries/lib-main flags = 1]
    SoSource 1: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/~~TrVkaG9ymW5b3v5btcoSWA==/com.bcferries-OTGPloeIiQX8oDv5HFkGKw==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
    SoSource 2: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /vendor/lib64 flags = 2]
    SoSource 3: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/lib64 flags = 2]
    Native lib dir: /data/app/~~TrVkaG9ymW5b3v5btcoSWA==/com.bcferries-OTGPloeIiQX8oDv5HFkGKw==/lib/arm64
 result: 0
       at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:896)
       at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoNameImpl(SoLoader.java:725)
       at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:649)
       at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:629)
       at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:577)
       at com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutor.<clinit>(HermesExecutor.java:20)
       at com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutorFactory.create(HermesExecutorFactory.java:29)
       at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1024)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

I have tried following workarounds to fix this problem, but none of them helped.

-> Disabling hermes in android/app/build.gradle

-> Pustting soloader dependecy in build.gradle file
`implementation 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.9.0+'`

-> Tried upgrading soloder dependecy to 0.10.1,
`implementation 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.1'`

-> On the way to upgrade react native version to latest one (in progress)

I'll update after verifying it on the latest version. Meanwhile, if someone has verified the same issue or has another workaround, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue after upgrading to latest react-native version?

Comment: I am already using the latest version of react native still facing same issue